# How to get selected checkbox value in a loop using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP while loop where I insert the following code to show On and Off button.

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch<?php echo $i ?>" <?php echo $status; ?>>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Now I want to get **hidden** (`hiddenID`) field value when the on-off button is changed but it's showing me undefined with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onoffswitch").change(function() {
      var hiddenID = $(this).attr('hiddenID');      
      alert(hiddenID);
    });
});
```

Why it's showing me undefined error?

Comment: you should be listening for `input`, not `div` - $('[name="hiddenID"]')

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` you are, at present, in the `onoffswitch` check box. It doesn't have an attribute `hiddenID`

also the `hiddenID` is not an attribute in it's parent element. It is a value of the `name` attribute.

use `$(this).prev().val()`

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onoffswitch").change(function() {
      var hiddenID = $(this).prev("[name=hiddenID]").val()
      alert(hiddenID);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, it's removed the error message but get the same id value every time. is there anything am I missing?

Comment: I think you are calling it in the wrong place. Try the code block

Comment: and this line `$(this).prev().val();` showing unefined error message and your updated is showing me same id value.

Comment: are you changing the value each time when the checkbox is toggled using ajax?

Comment: The code I have posted is in the php while loop. Here I am using hidden input field to show the id value which is different. Now I want to alert this hidden id value when checkbox is changed

Comment: fill your code with some sample data. So that I can inspect on it.

Comment: Well, use this line `var hiddenID = $(this).find("[name='hiddenID']").val()` will solved the error.

Comment: find is for selecting childrens. I think there is something wrong